# Highcharts tooltip jumping with combined scatter/bubble chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, scatter-plot, bubble-chart

I'm not sure if there is much I can give here code wise, but I am running into a problem with the tooltip in highcharts for a combined bubble/scatter chart. It is worth noting that in the case I am working with now, there is only a single point in either series, so only two things on the chart at once.

If I chart two series of bubbles, like this for example:

```
myChart.addSeries({
    name: name1,
    color: '#000000',
    data: firstSeries,
    type: 'bubble'
}, true);
myChart.addSeries({
    name: name2,
    color: '#058DC7',
    data: secondSeries,
    type: 'bubble'
}, true);
```

The tooltips work perfectly. I can mouse over one bubble and see the tooltip, then mouse over another and see the tooltip.

But, if I do the exact same thing only replacing either of the "bubble" with "scatter", I run into some weird behavior where if I mouse over the bubble I can see the tooltip until my mouse moves. If the mouse moves even a single pixel, Highcharts will suddenly display the tooltip on the scatter point as if I am moused over the scatter point. If I move my mouse away from the bubble, the tooltip on the scatter disappears.

The scatter tooltip behaves as expected when moused over. If it matters, I have disabled stickyTracking and have the snap set to 10. Setting the snap didn't seem to fix anything. Before I disabled stickyTracking, my mouse being anywhere on the chart would result in the tooltip for the scatter point being displayed.

Comment: Hi, could you please post live example of your issue, so we can investigate the problem?